# Theory behind the MAT_HIGH_EXPLOSIVE_BURN in LS-DYNA

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for the reference of the high explosive material model in LS-DYNA, which is represented by keyword MAT_HIGH_EXPLOSIVE_BURN. The theory manual has an entry for this material model but it is quite vague and does not point to a good reference. Does anyone know a good literature behind it?